# loading both tabs and attaching plugin in document.ready

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using tabs and JQuery plugin for file upload. I'm doing teh file upload in one of teh tabs.I want to load tabs first and then attach the plugin code when the document is ready. But, only one of it work. When the tabs are loaded the plugin code is disabled. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({ 
             blah..blah
});
```

The 'fileupload' is in the fourth tab in a total of 6 tabs.

How can I have the tabs load and still have the plugin code execute. Thanks

Comment: What is the tabs() command? If it is a method that dynamically adds the tabs you need to move your fileupload-call to its complete-event.

Comment: tabs() is not a method. It initializes the tabs.